# Increment data array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have array with following structure/data:

```
1: Object
-2: Object
-- name : test
-- username : test
-- email : test@email.com
-4: Object
-- name : test4
-- username : test4
-- email : test4@email.com
-5: Object
-- name : test5
-- username : test5
-- email : test5@email.com
```

My js:

```
for (var i =0; i < 5; i++){
    var r = $('#name').val(datas[1][i].name);
    console.log(r)
}
```

Why is `datas[1][i].name` undefined?

I want `var i` to increment.

Comment: Your loop starts from `0`. Your data starts on `2`.. So, `datas[1][0]` and `datas[1][1]`  are undefined.

Comment: If the data sample shown is accurate, then `datas[1][i]` will be undefined when `i` is `0` and `1` before the loop reaches `2`. Check `if (datas[1].hasOwnProperty(i))` before trying to reference it.

Comment: It would help greatly if you define your object/array using actual javascript.

Comment: i want loop in for increment. when datas look like..
`datas[1][0]` 
`datas[1][1]` 
`datas[1][2]` 
`datas[1][3]`
but use var i for increment..

Comment: @CyRossignol its work's thaks...

Answer (score 1):

Your index on `datas[1]` is not incremental so you **CANT** use `for (var i =0; i < 5; i++)` for this.

You can use something like:

```js
var datas = {
 1 : {
  2 : {
   name : 'test',
   username : 'test',
   email : 'test@email.com',
  },
  4 : {
   name : 'test4',
   username : 'test4',
   email : 'test4@email.com',
  },
  5 : {
   name : 'test5',
   username : 'test5',
   email : 'test5@email.com',
  }
 } 
};
    
for ( var key in datas[1] ) {
 console.log( datas[1][key].name );
}
```